# Bahamas Digital Elevation Model

Tags: geospatial

Does anyone know where I can find a digital elevation model for the Bahamas? North Bimini specifically? I'm looking to model the topography in ArcGIS.

Comment: https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/ is sort of the "go to" source for this.

Answer (score 1):

National Ocean Service (NOS) Office of Coast Survey 
U.S. Bathymetric & Fishing Maps has bathymetry coverage [you can see what's available on this map of the data](https://maps.ngdc.noaa.gov/viewers/fishmaps/).